# How to efficiently read, encode and store data from the serial port in Python?

Tags: performance, python-3.x, serialization, matplotlib, serial-port

The purpose of the program: Read serial data from the serial port, convert them to int and store them into a list. This data will be later processed and printed in real-time using matplotlib.

The problems:

1. The list is taking too long to be created (several seconds, maybe
   minutes).
   ps: the size o the list is n = 1024.
2. After all that minutes to create the list I get this:
   "(...)
   File "C:\Users\ianmc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 645, in recache
   raise RuntimeError('xdata and ydata must be the same length')
   RuntimeError: xdata and ydata must be the same length  "

   Probably the plot arguments got different lengths but why?

The code:

```
import serial
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


dt = 0.01
Fs = 44000.0                     # sample rate
timestep = 1.0/Fs                # sample spacing (1/sample rate)
n = 1024                         # size of the array data (BUFFER SIZE)
t = np.arange(0, (n/100), dt)    # t range
w = 10000                        # frequency of the input

#initialize data list
data = [0] * n

#initialize magnitude list
magnitude = [0] * (n//2)

# open and prepare serial port
ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600, timeout=8,
                    parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, rtscts=1)


# calculates the fft dB
def createMagnitudeDB(magnitude):
    magnitudeDB = 20 * (math.log(magnitude,10))
    return magnitudeDB

def update(data):
    # update the curves with the incoming data
    timeCurve.set_ydata(data[0])
    freqCurve.set_ydata(data[1])
    return timeCurve, freqCurve,

def generateData():
    # simulate new data coming in
    while True:

        # THE EFFICIENCY PROBLEM IS IN THIS FOR
        # Read data from arduino
        for i in range(n):     #while you are taking data
            PreData = ser.readline()
            data.append(int(PreData))


        # fft computing and normalization
        magnitude = np.fft.fft(data)/n
        magnitude = np.abs(magnitude[range(n//2)])

        # calculates the fft dB
        magnitude_dB = [createMagnitudeDB(x) for x in magnitude]

        yield (data, magnitude)


fig = plt.figure()

# create time graph axis
timeGraph = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
timeGraph.set_ylim(-200, 200)
timeGraph.set_xlim([0, n])
timeGraph.set_xlabel('Time')
timeGraph.set_ylabel('Amplitude')

# create frequency graph axis
freqGraph = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
freqGraph.set_ylim([0, 70])
freqGraph.set_xlim([0, (Fs/2)])
freqGraph.set_xlabel('Freq (Hz)')
freqGraph.set_ylabel('Magnitude')


#get frequency range
k = np.arange(n)
T = n/Fs
freq = k/T               # two sides frequency range
freq = freq[range(n//2)] # one side frequency range

# plot the curves
timeCurve, = timeGraph.plot(np.linspace(0, 1, n),'b')
freqCurve, = freqGraph.plot(freq, magnitude,'g')

# animate the curves
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, generateData,
                              interval = 10, blit=True)

# open window
plt.show()

# close serial connection
ser.close()
```

Another piece of information: If instead of using the serial port I generate my own data the program works fine, here is it:

```
def generateData():
    # simulate new data coming in
    while True:

        nse = np.random.randn(len(t))
        r = np.exp(-t/0.05)
        cnse = np.convolve(nse, r)*dt
        cnse = cnse[:len(t)]
        data =  100*np.sin(2*np.pi*t) + 500*cnse


        # fft computing and normalization
        magnitude = np.fft.fft(data)/n
        magnitude = np.abs(magnitude[range(n//2)])

        # calculates the fft dB
        magnitude_dB = [createMagnitudeDB(x) for x in magnitude]

        yield (data, magnitude)
```

The only difference is the generateData function and not using the open/close serial commands, thats why I don't understand the "xdata and ydata must be the same length" error on the other code (data has the same length on both codes)

**EDIT :**

The program is receiving data via bluetooth from an arduino that is reading an analog pin. I measured the reading time of the arduino and it's taking "0.015ms" to read each value. To read and print each value it's taking "3.1ms". The reading time of the computer for each value is "100ms".

Which means it will take n*100(ms) to create the list, being n the number of elements of the list. The minimum 'n' I could use is 256, this would take 25.6s to create the list. Thats just too long for a real-time graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem 1:

It's hard to tell from the outside how long your data aquisition takes and if this is 'too long' or just normal. The speed of the serial connection is 9600 bits per second, but we do not know how many bits you read in. You could time the data aquisition using the `time` module (`start = time.time()` `stop = time.time()` `print (stop - start)` ) and see if this exceeds your expectations. In this case it may also be an option to update the graph after each data read.

However the real problem probably lies in the fact that you try to call `generateData()` every 10 milliseconds (specified in `animation.FuncAnimation(..., interval = 10, ...)`). This might cause problems because the data aquisition surely takes longer than that. That is, even if you only read one bit at a time, reading 1024 bits would take ~ 100 milliseconds. 
So it may either help to set the interval to a more reasonable number or to not use `FuncAnimation` at all and simply plot the data once it is read in.

#### Problem 2:

The problem is that you initialize the `timeGraph` with an array of length `n`, `timeCurve, = timeGraph.plot(np.linspace(0, 1, n))`.
At this point your array data already has `n` zeros in it. In the first iteration you append another `n` numbers read from the serial port. So at this point `data` is `2*n` long.

The problem is now that you only update the ydata of the plot(`timeCurve.set_ydata(data[0])`, so the x axis still has `n` values (implicitely set at the beginning), and this does not match the `2*n` values you want to set to the y axis of that plot.

Solution:

1. The first option would be to reinitialize data in every iteration, such that it always has `n` entries.
2. The second option would be to update the plot via

   ```
   timeCurve.set_data(np.arange(len(data[0])), data[0])
   ```

   setting both the x and y data to arrays of the same length.

Comment: I measured the reading time and It varies from "0.06s" to "0.16s"
with an average around 0.1s. The appending time is printing 
"0.000000s". I don't know if i did something wrong or if it's 
just too fast.  
This means that if I'm creating a list with 1024 numbers it would take
1024*0.1 = 102.4s to create the list. Its a huge delay that makes
impossible to plot a real-time graph. Even if I change the 'n' to 256
it would still be a 25.6s delay.
I don't think It's possible to plot the graph each time I read one
data because to calculate the FFT I necessarily need a sequence of 
numbers.

Comment: I updated the post with some new information about the timings. The problem really is the reading time of the serial port. Could the baudrate increase make things better?

Comment: If the data reading takes ~0.1s that would match exactly my prediction. Appending data to a list is indeed a very fast operation, not accurately measurable with `time`, so no worries about that. Did you actually try the script and measured 102 s for the list creation?

Comment: Increasing baudrate might work. Mind that the device must be set to that baudrate and that setting a baudrate which is too high might make it impossible to communicate with the device. All of those questions are really specific to your configuration, and I think you should create a new [MCVE] (without any matplotlib plotting) and ask a new question about it, specifying your exact hardware. SO may not be the best place for such a question, but if you chose to post it here, make sure to use the `arduino` and `bluetooth` tag.

Comment: The 102s I just predicted. But thanks anyway I will do what you recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Appending 1024 items to a list does not take several seconds. Reading 1024 lines from your device might take seconds or minutes, but I don't think we can help with that.

In `generateData` you append items to `data` but you never delete them, so `data` grows without limits. I guess you want to recreate `data` from the start in every iteration of the loop:

```
# Read data from arduino
data = []
for i in range(n):     #while you are taking data
    PreData = ser.readline()
    data.append(int(PreData))
```

Comment: Could it be because I'm using bluetooth to receive the serial data? The problem 2 appears to be solved. Thanks.